# Fixed Title with scroll elements

Tags: android, flutter, scrollview

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to make simple one screen, with FIXED TITLE and below it scrolable "child or Column" with few elements like in the screenshot.
There will be two elements initially and I want them in center of screen,
but when third element is added then scrollview need to kick in for smaller screens
, so the title stays fixed but elements scrolable.
here is current code which scrolling all including title.
Thanks in advance:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

      color: Color.fromRGBO(246, 246, 246, 1.0),
      child: SafeArea(
          child: Material(


            child: Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(

                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0,bottom: 20.0),

                        child: Text(
                          'Lorem Ipsum',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 53, 43, 1.0),
                              fontSize: 40.0,                            
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    _item(context, 'ITEM_1', 'Title1', 'ico_01.png'),
                    _item(context, 'ITEM_2', 'Title2', 'ico_02.png'),
                    _thirdItem
                        ? _item(
                        context, 'ITEM_3', 'Title3', 'ico_03.png')
                        : Container(),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should demonstrate how to have a fixed title. Note the Column's mainAxisSize is set to MainAxisSize.max and SingleChildScrollView is wrapped in a Flexible, which results in the SingleChildScrollView occupying the remainings space and it enables scrolling.

```
class FixedTitleScrollView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            'Fixed Title',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(78, 53, 43, 1.0),
                fontSize: 40.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _item(),
                _item(),
                _item(),
                _item(),
                _item(),
                _item(),
                _item(),
                _item(),
                _item(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _item() {
    Color color = Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff));
    return Container(
      color: color,
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(color.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Try modifying this to your needs. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: thank you for your answer it helps,
I will only have two (box like elements) in that scrollView, but the third one is added later, is it possible to have those two boxes in center of screen (below fixed title) but when a third is added, then all of them will be spread evenly
in the rest of the screen (below title). (A scrollView is mainly there for smaller screen sizes and rotation) 
I have no rights to post pictures, but I hope you know what I mean.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, if you did not have a SingleChildScrollView you could set the Column's mainAxisAlignment property to change based upon your _thirdItem boolean. However I don't think this is going to work as the Column is wrapped inside the SingleChildScrollView, you can't set the Column's mainAxisSize to Max since this would result in infinite height, so I am unsure how you should proceed. 

You could possibly create a tile-like widget with a Container widget with a fixed size and a Column as the container's child. Add the items in the column and try to style it like you want. Probably not optimal.